# Putting salt and ice in a can causes frost to form, while doing this again without salt will only cause condensation, why?

Tags: water, salt

If this is the wrong place to ask my question, then blame my friend, and also tell me where to post this since I'm new. Anyway, we did an experiment in class where we took 2 soda cans with no top. We filled both 3/4 the way full with ice but only put salt in one of them. The one with salt formed frost while the one without salt on formed condensation. It wasn't really explained very well though. My theory is that the salt melts the ice, but the melted liquid is still below freezing. Since it is liquid it gets good contact with the can cooling it down to below freezing, causing frost. With the one with no salt, I think the solid ice can't get good contact with the can, so it won't be able to cool to below freezing. The liquid also is below freezing. This means only condensation will form. Now, I would still expect the ice to just move so that way it is making contact with the can cooling it down until it is below freezing, making frost. Why doesn't that happen? Thanks for any answers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melting ice occurs at $0$°C, and stays at this temperature. It will never be colder. But a mixture of melting ice and salt is always at a temperature lower than $0$°C. The minimum temperature obtained with a precise mixture is -$21$°C. Usually, without special care, the temperature is between $0$°C and -$21$°C. If some mixture ice + salt is in a soda can, condensation of atmospheric water vapor on the outer part of the can produces frost (or ice), because its temperature is under $0$°c. If the can contains only ice plus water (no salt), its temperature is never lower than $0$°C; the condensation of the humid air can only produce liquid water droplets, and no frost.

Comment: How does the ice remain frozen if it isn't below 0 degrees Celsius?

Comment: A mixture of pure water + ice remains at $0$°C as long as one of these two phases do coexist. This mixture is even the definition of zero degree Celsius.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so why does frost not form in the non-salt can since the ice should cool it down to below freezing?

Comment: Pure ice is and stays at zero degree if water is present. It cannot be cooler than $0$°C. If the temperature of the mixture ice + water goes down to <$0$°C, the water will be totally transformed into ice.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thanks!